# Getting SQL syntax error in INSERT query in wordpress database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

i am using below insert query adding custom filed for all wordpress post, but getting Sql Syntax error i dont know where i m doing wrong

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID AS post_id, 'CustomField'
AS meta_key 'MyValue AS meta_value
FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'CustomField')
'' AND post_type = 'post';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed comma for separation of columns and single quote to wrap string.

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID AS post_id, 
       'CustomField' AS meta_key, 
       'MyValue' AS meta_value
FROM   wp_posts 
WHERE  ID NOT IN
       (SELECT post_id 
        FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = 'CustomField')
       AND post_type = 'post';
```

An alternative of using `NOT IN` is by joining two tables,

```
INSERT  INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT  a.ID AS post_id, 
        'CustomField' AS meta_key, 
        'MyValue' AS meta_value
FROM    wp_posts a
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b
            ON  a.ID = b.post_id AND 
                b.meta_key = 'CustomField'
WHERE   a.post_type = 'post' AND
        b.post_id IS NULL
```